# How can I get a real difference between two dates in months?

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql, difference

My problem is, when I set the date range as the following

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME2 = '2023-01-31 08:00:00.0000000';  
DECLARE @enddate   DATETIME2 = '2023-02-01 08:00:00.0000000';   
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, @startdate, @enddate)
```

The result is one.

Comment: So what are you expecting here? February and January *are* 1 month different. `DATEDIFF` measures ticks, and the month *ticked* once between those two days (when the month changed from January to February).

Comment: Do you mean [`real`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) difference? What precision is required? What range, e.g. thousands of years? How long is the reference month? 28, 29, 30, or 31 days? Are leap seconds significant? We need to know a lot more to help with the calculation.

Comment: The months is zero at the specified date range. If we replace the @enddate with '2023-02-28 08:00:00.0000000' the correct value is 1 month. (the year is not leap year)

Comment: Can you specify "correct value" as an algorithm? End-of-month to end-of-month at the same time of day looks easy. We'll assume that anything less than 28 days is zero L. Kvri months. What is precisely one L. Kvri month after 2023-01-15 00:00:00? Is it 14 days after the first day of February or 16 days prior to the last day?

Comment: John Cappelletti, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps more that you are looking for, but here is a Table-Valued Function.  Can be called individually or within a `CROSS APPLY` if your data is in a table.

**Example**

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME2 = '2023-01-31 08:00:00.0000000';  
DECLARE @enddate   DATETIME2 = dateadd(month,6,getdate()) --'2023-02-01 08:00:00.0000000';   

Select * 
From [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed](@startdate,@enddate)
```

**Results**

```
Years   Months  Days    Hours   Minutes Seconds
0       5       24      3       2       49
```

**The function if interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed] (@D1 DateTime,@D2 DateTime)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cteBN(N)   as (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cteRN(R)   as (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))-1 From cteBN a,cteBN b,cteBN c),
         cteYY(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(YY,R,@D1))From cteRN R Where DateAdd(YY,R,@D1)<=@D2),
         cteMM(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(MM,R,D))  From (Select Top 12 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteYY P Where DateAdd(MM,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteDD(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(DD,R,D))  From (Select Top 31 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteMM P Where DateAdd(DD,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteHH(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(HH,R,D))  From (Select Top 24 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteDD P Where DateAdd(HH,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteMI(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(MI,R,D))  From (Select Top 60 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteHH P Where DateAdd(MI,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteSS(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(SS,R,D))  From (Select Top 60 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteMI P Where DateAdd(SS,R,D)<=@D2)

    Select [Years]   = cteYY.N
          ,[Months]  = cteMM.N
          ,[Days]    = cteDD.N
          ,[Hours]   = cteHH.N
          ,[Minutes] = cteMI.N
          ,[Seconds] = cteSS.N
          --,[Elapsed] = Format(cteYY.N,'0000')+':'+Format(cteMM.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteDD.N,'00')+' '+Format(cteHH.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteMI.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteSS.N,'00')
     From  cteYY,cteMM,cteDD,cteHH,cteMI,cteSS
)
--Max 1000 years
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed] ('1991-09-12 21:00:00.000',GetDate())
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! It seems tome it works well. But I don't exactly know how it works. Could you explain it to us? Just focusing to the month please.

Comment: Hi John Cappelletti, One more things, what does the cteBN and cteRN means?

Comment: @L.Kvri  Very simply we create an ad-hoc numbers/tally table.   Then we the max number of observations for Year (cteYY), Month (cteMM), Day (cteDD) ...    You certainly can comment out / remove the unnecessary CTEs like cteDD,cteHH,cteMI and cteSS

Comment: @L.Kvri cteBN is cteBaseNumber which is simply 10 digits / rows.   cteRN or cteRowNumber is essentially a CROSS JOIN which makes 10 rows into 1000 (10*10*10)

Comment: Nice solution but it doesn't work for Leap Years.  Try using the dates of 2000-01-31 and 2000-02-01 and see that it comes up with the incorrect answer of 1 day instead of 2.

Comment: @JeffModen There is 1 day between Jan 31 and Feb 1 and not two.  Perhaps you had another example in mind?    2000-02-29 to  2001-02-28  shows 1 year even

Comment: Omg.  I apologize, John.  Thanks for the feedback.  I don't know what I was thinking.  It should have been 2000-02-28 and 2000-03-01.  And, to be sure, I didn't test that.

Comment: @JeffModen   https://dbfiddle.uk/np_hutX3  Two Days.

Comment: I just tested it with the correct dates and yeah... it definitely supports Leap Years.  I really apologize for the mistake, John.

Comment: I tried to change my vote just as soon as i found out about the mistake I made.  It's been more than 8 hours and this cite won't allow me to change my vote unless you make even a minor change in the post.

Comment: That did the trick, John.  Vote changed.